# VueJS - Datalist input not clearing value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, html-datalist

I have a vue componenent that scans a QR code and inputs some information into a database upon success. This works great. However, once the data gets sent successfully I want to clear my datalist input field like so: `$('#adduser').val('');`, but nothing is working. The input remains filled in.

[image]

Here is my code at present..

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="message">{{ error }}</p>
        <div class="qr-fullscreen">
            <p class="decode-result" style="color:#ccc">Scanned: <strong style="color:#fff">{{ name }}</strong>
                <br>
                <input name="adduser" id="adduser" @input="addParticipation(user.upn)" class="form-control user_input" type="text" v-model="user.upn" list="manual" placeholder="Manually add an attendee">
                <datalist id="manual">
                    <option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="user.upn">{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}} (Year {{user.year}})</option>
                </datalist>
            </p>
            <qrcode-stream @decode="onDecode" @init="onInit" />
            <a v-bind:href="'/admin/sessions/'+this.session.id" class="qr-fullscreen-close">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { QrcodeStream } from 'vue-qrcode-reader';

    export default {

        mounted() {
            $('.loading').hide();
        },

        components: { QrcodeStream },

        data () {
            return {
                result: '',
                error: '',
                name: 'No one scanned',
                user: [],
                objectItem: {},
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onDecode (result) {
                this.result = result;
                this.addParticipation(this.result);
            },

            addParticipation(upn){

                var last_character = upn[upn.length-1];
                if(isNaN(last_character)){}else{

                    let currentObj = this; // important?
                    axios.post('/api/session_capture', {
                        session_id: this.session.id,
                        upn: upn,
                        api_token: localStorage.getItem('api_token')
                    })
                        .then((response) => {
                            //var audio = new Audio(require('audio/snap.mp3'));
                            //audio.play();
                            if (response.data.message) {
                                this.message(response.data.message, 4000);
                            } else {
                                this.playSound();
                                this.message(response.data.name + ' added successfully', 2000);
                                this.name = response.data.name;
                                $('#adduser').val('');
                            }


                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            currentObj.output = error;
                            console.log(currentObj.output);
                        });
                }
            },
            message($message,$time){
                $('.message').text($message).fadeIn(500, function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.message').fadeOut(500);
                    }, $time);
                });
            },
            playSound() {
                const path = this.root+'/audio/snap.mp3';
                const audio = new Audio(path);
                var playPromise = audio.play();

                if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                    playPromise.then(_ => {
                        console.log('Did you hear that?');
                    })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(`playSound error: ${error}`);
                        });
                }
            },

            async onInit (promise) {
                try {
                    await promise
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
                        this.error = "ERROR: you need to grant camera access permisson"
                    } else if (error.name === 'NotFoundError') {
                        this.error = "ERROR: no camera on this device"
                    } else if (error.name === 'NotSupportedError') {
                        this.error = "ERROR: secure context required (HTTPS, localhost)"
                    } else if (error.name === 'NotReadableError') {
                        this.error = "ERROR: is the camera already in use?"
                    } else if (error.name === 'OverconstrainedError') {
                        this.error = "ERROR: installed cameras are not suitable"
                    } else if (error.name === 'StreamApiNotSupportedError') {
                        this.error = "ERROR: Stream API is not supported in this browser"
                    }
                    message(this.error);
                }
            }
        },

        props:[
            'session',
            'root',
            'users'
            ],
    }



</script>

<style>
    .message {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2001;
        padding: 10%;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        color: #fff;
        display:none;
    }
    .user_input{
        margin-top: 5px !important;
        width: 90vw !important;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a dedicated property for your input.

```
 data () {
    return {
             ... // rest remains same
                currentUser
            }
        },
```

Bind your input's `v-model` to `currentUser`

```
<input name="adduser"
       id="adduser" 
       @input="addParticipation(user.upn)"
       class="form-control user_input" 
       type="text" 
       v-model="currentUser" 
       list="manual" placeholder="Manually add an attendee">
```

Where you want to clear your data assign `currentUser` an empty value.
So change this :`$('#adduser').val('');` into this : `this.currentUser=''`.

And **Stop using JQuery**. If you are using Vue, Angular or React kind of frameworks they have their own ways to do things. Use them instead of creating extra or legacy dependencies.

And if you are using `v-for` provide a `v-bind:key` where it is possible.

```
<datalist id="manual">
    <option v-for="user in users"
            v-bind:value="user.upn"
            v-bind:key="user.upn">
           {{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}} (Year {{user.year}})
   </option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you Eldar. After years of spaghetti php and jquery I'm starting out with Laravel and Vue. I really do need to fix my reliance on jQuery - old habits die hard! I will fix my code :)